# PyCharm automatically change script

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

In PyCharm, is there a way to automatically change the script in Run/Debug Configurations to the file I am currently editing? Currently, when I create a new file, I manually edit the Script in Configurations to the one I want to run.

Comment: I don't think so.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click in context menu and click `Run 'your_script'` or press `Ctrl+Shift+F10`

Found here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/